# Why won't glVertexPointer render the same content as glBegin/glEnd?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm attempting to write some simple test programs in LWJGL.  I've constructed a ByteBuffer object full of floating point values representing a 2D grid of points.

When I render the grid using glBegin/glEnd I see the proper output:

```
    float[] values = new float[MESH_SIZE * MESH_SIZE * 4];
    heightField.position(0);
    heightField.asFloatBuffer().get(values);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < MESH_SIZE * MESH_SIZE; ++i) {
        int offset = i * 4;
        glVertex3f(values[offset], values[offset + 1], values[offset + 2]);
    }
    glEnd();
```

When I render it using glVertexPointer, it fails to produce anything other than a single point at the center of the screen.

```
    heightField.position(0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 4 * 4, heightField);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, MESH_SIZE * MESH_SIZE);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

My reading of the OpenGL and lwjgl docs is that that these two pieces of code should produce the same output, but they clearly don't.  What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like in the first one you convert the heightField object into an array of floats. But in the second one you're passing a pointer to the object, which includes its vtable and all the other fun stuff in addition to the data.

Comment: The glVertexPointer is an LWJGL method that explicitly takes a FloatBuffer, or ByteBuffer, depending on the overload you call.  Java is strongly typed and it's not possible to simply pass a pointer where you intended to pass an array.

Comment: The way you build your mesh you could/should set the stride value to 0, indicating tightly packed data.

Comment: @datenwolf But then he would have to use `4` instead of `3` as size (and hope that the fourth component is always `1`).

Comment: @ChristianRau: Oh, good catch; but you shouldn't leave arrays uninitialized anyway; so initializing the %3 elements to 1 would make sense.

Comment: The sample code doesn't feature the population of the heightField.  The choice of 16 bytes as the stride is intentional, because eventually the heightfield will be populated via OpenCL, which recommends aligning work units on 32 byte boundaries, while tightly packed vertices would be on 24 byte boundaries.  If you look at the two pieces of code you'll see that the stride is the same in both, and is implied by the 'i * 4' offset in the first piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the problem isn't visible in the question.  Eventually experimentation revealed that the construction of the buffer was at fault.  I was using this code to initialize the buffer

```
    heightField = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertex_count * 4 * 4);
```

However, which I switched to this line, the code started working

```
    heightField = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(vertex_count * 4 * 4);
```

It turns out that `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` does not default to the hardware byte order, but instead defaults to Java's byte order.  This means that when passed in to the native GL function, the floats in the buffer had reversed byte order.  That's why I saw a single dot in the center of the screen.  The 0,0 point was the same either way, but all the other bytes were probably wildly outside of the rendering viewport.

Comment: In case you did not know there is a utility class in LWJGL called BufferUtils which should create the buffers with the correct ordering for you. http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.html

Comment: If you look closely you'll see that's what I'm using on the second line.